# sonata: Dealing with sonata_type_model (one-to-many)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

1- I have an Entity:

### EmployeeMedicalService

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="employee_medical_file")
 */
class EmployeeMedicalService extends BaseEntity
{

   //
   // Some
   // Fields
   //


    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PersonnelBundle\Entity\Lookup\Lookup")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="medical_service_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $medicalService;

   //
   // getters
   // & setters
   //
```

---

2- Another Entity:

### Lookup

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="lookup")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="name")
 */
class Lookup extends BaseEntity
{
    // const ...
    const TYPE_MEDICAL_SERVICE = 'medical_service';
    // more constants ...

    public function __construct($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

     //
     // Some Fields
     //

    /**
     * @var string
     * --stuff--
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $type;

    //getters
    // &setters
```

---

Now in the

### EmployeeMedicalServiceAdmin

```
protected function configureFormFields(\Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper $formMapper)
    {

        $msquery = $this->getModelManager()
                ->getEntityManager('PersonnelBundle:Lookup\Lookup')
                ->createQueryBuilder();

        $msquery->select('l')->from('PersonnelBundle:Lookup\Lookup', 'l')->where('l.type = :type')
                ->orderBy('l.name', 'ASC')
                ->setParameter('type', 'medical_service');

        $formMapper
                ->add(..)

                ->add('medicalService', 'sonata_type_model', array(
                    'label' => 'personnel.employee.medical_service.form.medical_service',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'required' => false,
                    'query' => $msquery,
                ))

                ->add(..)
        ;
    }
```

### ** My Problem: **

I need the form for add new lookup(medical service)  from inside the EmployeeMedicalService Admin Form to be preloaded  with the field **Type** value set to **'medical_service'** When I attempt to add a new Medical Service from inside the EmployeeMedicalService Admin Form or else a new lookup is added without the value if **Type** set to **NULL**

---

This is the

### LookupAdmin

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
                ->add('name', 'text', array(
                    'label' => 'personnel.lookup.form.name'
                ))
                ->add('type', 'hidden', array(
                    'label' => 'personnel.lookup.form.type',
                ))
        ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect ajax request for the popup form you will notice extra query parameters, such as `pcode`. You could check if this parameter exists and equals `EmployeeMedicalServiceAdmin` admin class code then set `lookup` type to `medical_service`.

**UPDATE**

Add this king of logic in the `getNewInstance()` method:

```
public function getNewInstance()
{
    $type = isset($_GET['pcode']) ? 'medical_service' : '';
    $instance = new \PersonnelBundle\Entity\Employee\EmployeeMedicalService($type);

    return $object;
}
```

Comment: I managed to find the "pcode" parameter and I tried this:                             if (isset($_GET['pcode']) && $_GET['pcode'] == 'sonata.admin.employee_medical_service') {
//What do I do here ?? 
}
And where do I implement this logic ??

THANKS very much for anwering

Comment: There is a problem: The Lookup has a constructor
    public function __construct($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }
Which requires the type to be set in order for the pop-up form to be loaded ..

Comment: well, dont use `parent::getNewInstance()` just create it yourself.

Comment: I changed it to 
    public function getNewInstance()
    {
        $instance = new \PersonnelBundle\Entity\Employee\EmployeeMedicalService();
.........
}
but No luck .. I don't see why this would make a difference

Comment: You create this entity based on `pcode` condition. If condition is met just pass 'medical_service' to the constructor, otherwise pass null. and dont forget to return this newly created instance.

Comment: I know I bothered you, but it's not working .. plus isset($_GET['pcode']) always returns false when dumped

Comment: Well, i just tested it on my local machine and it works like a sharm. Method `getNewInstance()` is called whenever adding form is shown. The main idea is to set default value for field `type` of entity `lookup` to `medical_service` if `$_GET['pcode']` exists.

Comment: I get the logic, but the mentioned problem is tha The add form does not open console shows (500 internal server error) ,,, unless I remove the __constructor from my Lookup(medical service) entity ..[Which is not a solution as I need the constructor]

Comment: I have updated `getNewInstance()` method in the answer

Comment: public function getNewInstance()
    {
        $instance = parent::getNewInstance();
        if (isset($_GET['pcode']) && $_GET['pcode'] == 'sonata.admin.employee_medical_service') { //What do I do here ?? 
            $instance = new \PersonnelBundle\Entity\Employee\EmployeeMedicalService();
            $instance->setMedicalService(new \PersonnelBundle\Entity\Lookup\Lookup('medical_service'));
        } else {
            $instance = new \PersonnelBundle\Entity\Employee\EmployeeMedicalService();
            $instance->setMedicalService(NULL);
        }
        return $instance;
    }

Comment: This is how it was before, I tried your method but nothing works unless I remove the __constructor from my Lookup entity .. and even then, The type is always set to null no matter what I do  ..
Nothing worked so far !!
I'm sorry It took so long